# Why the font awesome icons are not working?

Tags: html, font-awesome

I dont know what details do you need. Code is very simple.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
                <ul class="sci">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-vk" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

details details  details  details  details  details  details  details  details

Comment: What about some information about your problem?

Comment: Hmm, if you set wrong the `integrity` attribute and the browser is blocking the resource, try to access the console and see if any error there

Comment: fab is version 5... you are using version 4

Answer (score 3):

`fab` [is not included](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/upgrading-from-version-4#changes) in the `4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css`.

Consider using up-to-date `5.15.1` cdn link (provided by [cdnjs.com](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/font-awesome)):

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<ul class="sci">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-vk" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

change **fab** to **fa**. you need to use font-awesome version 5 to use fab

```
<i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

or use font-awesome 5 cdn link

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css
```

Comment: Thank you, but on their website it was fab :0

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

use latest `CSS` and `JS`.

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/js/all.min.js
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-+4zCK9k+qNFUR5X+cKL9EIR+ZOhtIloNl9GIKS57V1MyNsYpYcUrUeQc9vNfzsWfV28IaLL3i96P9sdNyeRssA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/js/all.min.js" integrity="sha512-F5QTlBqZlvuBEs9LQPqc1iZv2UMxcVXezbHzomzS6Df4MZMClge/8+gXrKw2fl5ysdk4rWjR0vKS7NNkfymaBQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
                <ul class="sci">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-vk" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to get the CDN link from the Font Awesome site. This is what it looks like:

```
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/9375920.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

(Don't use this one, the ID in there is not valid). Include it in the head of your code and it should work fine.

Comment: This is what it looks like: https://kit.fontawesome.com/7b7972335d.js

(posted it as a script tag in my previous comment)